# Are these functions Injective ,Surjective or Bijective? And why?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
I solved for the values of x for the first function and found that it was Bijective. Also assumed the second function was just x^3 which is again Both Injective and Surjective i.e Bijective. I solved values for the third but don´t know how to check for Injectivity etc.

Any alternate ways to solve the problem is Highly appreciated. This site helps me think differently as in problem solving techniques!!

Comment: The second function is a parabola with the left side negative and no point at 0. For g try to see if you ever get any duplicate values. And for s, for how many x does sin(x)=0? To select one. How does this reflect the definition of one to one?

Comment: To answer your question. It doesn´t work one to one obviously but it is Surjective as all the y values have independent x values.

Comment: can u help me understand the second function a bit

Comment: try plotting the second fucntion its not a parabola but a x^3 function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proving $h$ is injective, you want to show:
$$h(x)=h(y) \iff x=y $$
Which can be proved with something like this:

From $h(x)=h(y)$ we write:
$$\frac{x^3}{|x|} = \frac{y^3}{|y|} $$ 
$$  \Rightarrow  x^2\frac{x}{|x|} = y^2\frac{y}{|y|}  $$ 
$$  \Rightarrow x^2 sign(x) = y^2 sign(y) $$ 
$$  \Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{y^2} = \frac{sign(y)}{sign(x)} $$ 
$$  \Rightarrow  \frac{sign(y)}{sign(x)} \geq 0 $$ 
$$  \Rightarrow sign(y) = sign(x) $$ 
$$  \Rightarrow x^2  = y^2  $$ 
$$  \Rightarrow x  = y  $$

Comment: please explain the signum part i got lost there as i have no idea what that is.

Comment: [sign(x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) is 1 if $x>1$ and -1 if $x<0$. Since we know $x^2/y^2 \geq 0$ we can conclude that $sign(y)/sign(x) \geq 0$, so x and y should have the same sign, so that the sign of their division be positive. Now that we know they have the same sign, we can remove this term from line 3, and we get $x^2=y^2$, so $x=y$ as we already established that $sign(x)=sign(y)$.

Comment: similarly how to check for surjectivitiy? i got this one lika a charm! :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to go from the definition for that one too. For [surjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) you need to show: 
$ \forall y\in R , \; \exists x\in R, f(x)=y$

For example for $h$, we can show that for each $y$, we can set $x = sign(y) \sqrt{y}$, and then we get $h(x) =y$

Comment: so that means the function is both injective and surjective?